# Can't set audio src in handlebars file

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-audio, handlebars.js

**home.handlebars**

```
<script>
function setAudio(media_src){
    console.log('media src: ' + media_src);

    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.src = media_src;
    player.load();
    player.play();
    return false;
}
</script>

<audio id='player' controls autoplay>

</audio>

<a href="#" id = "link" onClick= "return setAudio({{this.id}});">Music</a>
```

I have confirmed that "this.id" contains a valid url. After clicking the href, the only thing that happens is that a "#" is appended to the address bar. The audio tag does not play anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I figured it out. Turns out I needed single-quotes around my parameter being passed to `setAudio()`:

```
<a href="#" id = "link" onClick= "return setAudio('{{this.id}}');">Music</a>
```